# Using CSS how to change only the 2nd column of a table

Tags: css

Using css only, how can I override the css of only the 2nd column of a table.

I can get to all of the columns using:

```
.countTable table table td
```

I can not get to the html on this page to modify it since it is not my site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 285, accepted):

You can use the `:nth-child` pseudo class like this:

```
.countTable table table td:nth-child(2)
```

Note though, this won't work in older browsers (or IE), you'll need to give the cells a class or use javascript in that case.

Comment: This will only give the second cell in each table, not the second cell in each row.  You need .countTable table table tr td:nth-child(2)

Comment: @Deeksy - That's not accurate, it doesn't care what the selector is. `nth-child` is applied after finding the element, and it's `nth` compared to whatever parent it has, no matter if it was in the selector or not.  You can see this working here: http://jsfiddle.net/JQQPz/

Comment: how about changing only the css of an element inside td:nth-child(2). Like <a> tag. is it going to be td a:nth-child(2){} ?

Comment: @ivory-santos just add the `a` at the end, e.g. `td:nth-child(2) a` to style links beneath that element.

Comment: Why do you have table twice (unlike other answers below)?

Comment: @UlFie See the original question's selector :)

Comment: Found this, 10 years later. Would just like to note that IE 11 indeed supports nth-child(2).

Answer (score 29):

Try this:

```
.countTable table tr td:first-child + td
```

You could also reiterate in order to style the others columns:

```
.countTable table tr td:first-child + td + td {...} /* third column */
.countTable table tr td:first-child + td + td + td {...} /* fourth column */
.countTable table tr td:first-child + td + td + td +td {...} /* fifth column */
```

Comment: I opted for this in a situation where the owners of the site maintaining the code were not developers and this gave them the ability to change the alignment of columns in their data tables in a very straight forward way that  although a little verbose, with comment like you have here, made it easy for them to know which selector block was for which column from the left. Again not the most elegant and efficient way, but it worked!

Answer (score 20):

To change only the second column of a table use the following:

**General Case:**

```
table td + td{  /* this will go to the 2nd column of a table directly */

background:red

}
```

**Your case:**

```
.countTable table table td + td{ 

background: red

}
```

Note: this works for all browsers (Modern and old ones) that's why I added my answer to an old question

Comment: What would be the tweak to just select the first column?

Using table td { ... } selects all cells in other columns as well.

Comment: @j4v1
table td { background: red;}  //  first column will have red background
table td + td { background: blue;} // rest will have blue

Answer (score -3):

You could designate a class for each cell in the second column.

```
<table>
<tr><td>Column 1</td><td class="col2">Col 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Column 1</td><td class="col2">Col 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Column 1</td><td class="col2">Col 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Column 1</td><td class="col2">Col 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I can't use this. Like I said, this isn't my page and so, I can't change the html.

Comment: @Duniyadnd this is not a good approach, compared to existing way of using selectors.

Answer (score -3):

on this web http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/columns.html i found that easy way

```
<table>
<col style="background-color: #6374AB; color: #ffffff" />
<col span="2" style="background-color: #07B133; color: #ffffff;" />
<tr>..
```

Comment: He said he can’t modify the HTML.