# Bold a column in knitr::kable(df)

Tags: r, knitr

I have a dataframe that looks as follows:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---
```{r}
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))

employ.data <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate)

knitr::kable(employ.data)
```
````

Does anyone know how to bold the salary column?

It's going to be in an html format in the end.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: May be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166168/how-to-bold-a-cell-in-a-table-kable-in-rmarkdown helps

Comment: Would that work in an html format? I changed up the question to make it clearer @akrun

Comment: For flexible formatting of tables for `html` output, you might look at the [`htmlTable` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmlTable/vignettes/general.html) or the [`FlexTable` function](http://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/articles/FlexTable.html) in the [`ReporteRs` package](http://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/).

Comment: Also check out [`formattable`](https://renkun.me/formattable/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS to do it, as described here:  [Using CSS how to change only the 2nd column of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535112/using-css-how-to-change-only-the-2nd-column-of-a-table).

You can just put the CSS directly into the text, outside of the code chunk, or in a separate file mentioned in the YAML header.  For example,

````
<style>
table td:nth-child(2){
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

```{r}
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))

employ.data <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate)

knitr::kable(employ.data)
```
````

This will change every table in the document; you may want a more specific selector.

I don't know a simple way to add a class to a particular table using `kable()` in R Markdown, but this kludge will do it.  In the CSS, use

```
<style>
table.salarytable td:nth-child(2){
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

to restrict the change to class `salarytable`, then in the code chunk use

```
knitr::kable(employ.data, "html", 
             table.attr = 'class="table table-condensed salarytable"'
```

to tell `knitr` to output HTML and give the table the usual class for an R Markdown table, as well as your own `salarytable` class.

Comment: Thank you! I think the 2nd option you gave would work best for my needs since there are going to be multiple tables with different formats. @user2554330